# I am using the ngx-bootstrap datepicker datesEnabled is not working

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using the ngx-bootstrap date picker. In that, I am using inline date picker

```
<bs-datepicker-inline [bsValue]="bsInlineValue" [datesEnabled]="enableDate" [bsConfig]="{containerClass: 'theme-inline', selectFromOtherMonth: false, showWeekNumbers: false, defaultViewDate : false}" (bsValueChange)="handleChangePicker($event)"></bs-datepicker-inline>
```

`datesEnabled` is not working for me I am getting error of `Can't bind to 'datesEnabled' since it isn't a known property of 'bs-datepicker-inline'.` my enableDate array is `[new Date('2020-04-06'), new Date('2020-04-08'), new Date('2020-04-11')];` how to solve this error

Comment: Does version changing work for u ? @techie18

Comment: @Çağrı ya it works, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your ngx-bootsrap version make last one. 5.6.2 version works

Comment: `bsValueChange` is not working bs-datepicker-inline